# Left section of header in fisheye

Tags: web, atlassian-fisheye

I wonder what is the name of the left section of header in atlassian fisheye.

[image]

For example, the right section of the header is **`system.header.item`**

I've already searched through source code of fisheye, but I still can't find an answer.

And so called ["documentation"](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/FECRUDEV/FishEye+Web+Item+Locations#FishEyeWebItemLocations-WebItemsListingandReference) of *FishEye Web Item Locations* is uncomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that section isn't pluggable at the moment (FishEye/Crucible 3.5.1 and older).

You can plug items on the right-hand side using the `system.header.item` section. You could also possibly use some non-api way to add items to the main header (one solution would be having a javascript resource in the `atl.general` (and possibly `atl.admin`) context that modifies the DOM appropriately).

If you'd like the plugin point added to the main header, make sure to add a [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/FE).